# Finding the maximum valued and different typed items in an object list by using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an object with two different variables inside.

Looks like: `ModelB.Text` and `ModelB.Value` and `ModelB.Attr`

I also have a list of this object and I am loading this `List<ModelB>` with the data like this:

```
ModelB.Text = "Car";
ModelB.Value = "345.23";
ModelB.Text = "Car";
ModelB.Value = "343.23";
ModelB.Text = "Car";
ModelB.Value = "323.23";
ModelB.Text = "Toy";
ModelB.Value = "45.23";
ModelB.Text = "Toy";
ModelB.Value = "45.22";
ModelB.Text = "Toy";
ModelB.Value = "45.43";
```

What I want to do is to find the maximum an minimum valued cars, toys, etc. and check them like `ModelB.Attr = "max";` or `ModelB.Attr = "min";`

So we have to mark the max an min of the each type of object. And yes all the data is `string` unfortunately and I am parsing it to decimal usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I won't bother here about parse error, culture and so on : these are business problems, not linq problem.

I don't know either what to do if several objects have the same max value : mark them all or not, so I mark the first one. To mark them all, replace First by ForEach

```
foreach(var grp in myList.GroupBy(o => o.Text))
    grp.First(g => decimal.parse(g.Value) == grp.Max(o => decimal.Parse(o.Value)).Attr="max";
```

EDIT : Here is the foreach implementation

```
foreach(var grp in myList.GroupBy(o => o.Text))
{
    string min = grp.Min(o => decimal.Parse(o.Value));
    string max = grp.Max(o => decimal.Parse(o.Value));
    foreach(var obj in grp.Where(o => o.Value == min)
        obj.Attr="min";
    foreach(var obj in grp.Where(o => o.Value == max)
        obj.Attr="max";
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't find a way to change it by ForEach?

Comment: This will do sorting of all items twice, also each item will be parsed two times.

Comment: Well no, this will not do sorting. This will get the min and max.. so yes it will browse the collection twice. This could be optimized, but it is harder to write (and then to read) so I don't know it is a good idea : depend on use case (if perf is a need or not)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var g in models.GroupBy(m => m.Text)
                       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(m => Decimal.Parse(m.Value)))
{
    g.First().Attr = "min";
    g.Last().Attr = "max";
}
```

In case if there is only one item of some type (e.g. car), then it will be marked as `"max"`. If you want to mark it as `"min"`, then change order of attributes applying.

Also if not all items have correct decimal values in `Value` properties, then you can add filtering.